# Php upload file view in wamp server

Tags: php

i am  newbie in php i have created upload file program using wamp server. my program is running correctly. but i want to view my file.where is my file uploaded. And how i can watch it on browser screen.Resolve my error.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>try</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="post">
Browser for file to Upload:<br>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="80"> <br>
    <input type="submit" id="u_button" name="u_button" value="Upload the file ">
    <br>
    <a href="<?php echo $_FILES['file'']['name']; ?>" >click here toview file</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>

//php file
<?php
$file_result="";
if($_FILES['file']['error']>0)
{
    $file_result .="No file uploaded or invalid file";
     $file_result .="Error code:".$_FILES["file"]["error"]."<br>";
}
else
{
     $file_result .=
         "Upload:".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br>".
          "Type:".$_FILES["file"]["type"]."<br>".
          "Upload:".($_FILES["file"]["size"]/ 1024)."Kb<br>".
        "Temp File:".($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]/ 1024)."<br>";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"C:".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    $file_result .="File Upload Successful!";
    echo $file_result;
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"];  
}
?>
```

[this is my html file result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlnIO.png)

[this is the result of phpfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXHUt.png)

[this is the error when i click on view my file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaUT1.png)

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me, that you can't access the file. Where does the link in:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_FILES['file'']['name']; ?>" >click here toview file</a>
```

point to? Is there a file and do you have the permission on Apache to access that folder?

Comment: i don't know how to give permission to Apache. "Moritz Moller."

Comment: you can see that here: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/setting-file-permissions-with-chmod-on-windows-for-apache-and-php and
here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/configuring.html

by the way, you have double '' in ['file''] here 

    <a href="<?php echo $_FILES['file'']['name']; ?>" >click here toview file</a>

remove them better. Maybe this is the source of your error, because there is no valid link created.

Comment: i don't understand any thing ,from your given link.